# Set field value in Django Form clean() method, if this field not passed in constructor

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I need set field value, not passed to Django Form constructor.

I have model and form like this:

```
class Message(models.Model):
    created     = models.DateTimeField()
    text        = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True)
    active      = models.BooleanField(default=False)

class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model   = Message
        exclude = ('created', 'active')

    def clean(self):
        # check if user is blocked
        if user.is_admin():
            self.cleaned_data['active'] = True
        return self.cleaned_data
```

**Expected**: if current user is admin - I need automatically set message as active. User should not pass this parameter by form.

**Actual**: I see that saved message always have flag "False" (I can delete condition and in this case I also see that message is not active).

Please help me understand, how can I do set this "**active**" flag in **clean()** method.

Comment: How and where does the "user" variable get set?

Comment: I white this for example. You can delete this condition or replace on somthing else. I have set self.cleaned_data['active'] = True but also I need tell Django Form that this field is used and need set this value to the object before save. I can do this with "initial" parameter for Form object, but I cant do this im my case. I need tell Django Form that I have used "active" field, but I dont know how to do this into a form method clean().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The previous answer would work, but I like encapsulating all the form's internal operations like what to show and what not, within the form. I know you mentioned you don't want to send a field value to the constructor, but if you don't mind sending the user, your solution would work.
i.e., your constructor:

```
def __init__(self, user):
    self.user = user
    super(BaseForm, self).__init__()
```

then in your clean, you just change the `user` to `self.user`.
There is another added benefit to this. Say tomorrow you want to assign more fields based on your user, you don't need to add anything to the views, you can simply add it to the form.

EDIT:
When you add a field to exclude, it is not available in the cleaned data. Instead, set its widget as hidden.

```
active = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)
```

EDIT 2: If you really don't want the field in the form
In this case, instead of overriding the clean, why don't you override the save?

```
def save (self):
    super(BaseForm, self).save()
    if user.is_admin():
        self.instance.active=True
    super(BaseForm, self).save()
```

Comment: User object - this not a problem. Problem is in not setted cleaned_data to saved object. If I set self.cleaned_data['active'] = True in result this field not affected. I need tell Form that I have used "active" field in this form processing, like initial data  passed in form constructor.

Comment: Just rechecked your form. The problem is, that when you exclude a field in a form, it is not available in the cleaned data. Instead, include the attribute, and set its widget to hidden. check my edit

Comment: I have set data to self.cleaned_data - this is well. But I need tell Django Form to use this field. How to do this?

Comment: In your case user can pass data from the web. But this not a good. I need automatically set this behaviour, and user should not pass "active" field value from the web. And in my form I set "active" field to ignored fields.

Answer (score 3):

Don't do this in the form's clean() method, do this in the view.

```
def your_view(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MessageForm(data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_message = form.save(commit=False)
            if user.is_admin():
                new_message.active = True
```

However, if you also want to handle the case where your user is **not** admin using the same form, you can look at incorporating similar logic in the form's init() instead of the view, probably by passing info about the user from the view to the form's init()

Comment: I describe below that I need do this in Model logic or in Form logic. In the view - this easy way not for my task. If user work in admin section - I need activate my custom logic. If I do this logic in view - this not work in all other places - and this not a good!

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
def message_form_factory(user):
    class MessageForm(forms.ModelForm):
        def clean(self):
            # check if user is blocked
            if user.is_admin():
                self.cleaned_data['active'] = True
            return self.cleaned_data
    return MessageForm
```

And in your view use:

```
form = message_form_factory(request.user)()
form = message_form_factory(request.user)(request.POST)
```

Comment: In Django admin I need use functional with custom logic. Your solution can be used in admin with custom form - but this additional code around the project. I think that this is not a good solution in my case. Thanks!

Comment: As far as I can read, you didn't mention anything about Django admin in your question..